# Question about tensor definition

Tags: modules, tensor-products, tensors

I am a newbie in tensor. In the Hungerford Grad. Algebra book, tensor product of modules is defined as follows.

Let $A$ and $B$ be, respectively, right and left $R$-modules. Let $F$ be the free abelian group on $A \times B$. Let $K$ be the subgroup of $F$ generated by elements of form: (with $a,a'\in A,b,b'\in B,r\in R$)

1. $(a+a',b)-(a,b)-(a',b)$;
2. $(a,b+b')-(a,b)-(a,b')$;
3. $(ar,b)-(a,rb)$

And so on.

In the end, I think I understand that tensor product of $A$ and $B$ over $R$ are linear combinations of cosets of the above elements (please correct me if I'm wrong).

My question is very elementary.

For number 1. above, is it equal to $(0,-b)$ or not (as I am just summing componentwise)? The question is also for number 2. Why must they be written in the above form instead if they are the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same question the first time I studied the tensor product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the free module on $A\times B$ that we will denote $F_R(A\times B)$, you have only **formal linear combinations** so $(a+a',b)-(a,b)-(a',b) \neq (0,-b)$ (else you would be summing component wise, which is not what you do here : you are not looking at the group $A\times B$ but at the free module generated by $A\times B$).

Let $G$ be the group generated by $\{(a+a',b)-(a,b)-(a',b),(a,b+b')-(a,b)-(a,b') , (a,rb)-(ra,b) \text{ such that } (a,b)\in A\times B ,\, r \in R\}$.
Then $A\otimes B$ is $ F_R(A\times B)$ quotiented out by $G$ .

The idea of tensor product is to construct a space $A\otimes B$ such that for every $R$-module $P$ we have a "natural" (I dont use this term randomly) bijection between $Bil_R(A\times B, P)$ and $Hom_R (A\otimes B, P)$. This is indeed the case with our construction, since we did exactly what was needed to have this bijection (check it if you want).

Comment: These difficulties, in my modest opinion, are a consequence of the over-formalization of Mathematics that has been going on over the last 50-80 years. I think it is insane to introduce tensors in this form to Math students. The best way to think of a tensor is as a multilinear form and the main idea behind is invariance under coordinate changes. The stress or the strain tensor in an elastic body, or the curvature tensor, etc are real examples. Otherwise, we risk to talk about things so general that we lose sight of interesting particular cases.

Comment: I understand, but I think both have to come together. Of course one should not forget the most common "concrete" examples when introducing tensors (or any mathematical object). But on the other hand, I have always found it very satisfying to have a very general description of things. I believe the real problem arises when you loose the balance between these two approaches, and in this I do agree with you

Comment: I definitely think that it is useful to develop abstract points of view, freeing  concepts from unnecessary assumptions. My point is more about the teaching. You take an unexperienced student and you throw at him such a definition, involving free spaces, modules, some quotient operation... and you justify all this on the basis of invariance.. I think it is more humane to explain that objects useful in Physics they must not depend on coordinates, what the transformation laws should look like, etc. The formalization comes only after, and sometimes I think it is a void exercise

Comment: @Popyaitte Ohhhh thanks to you, I think I got it now. In the free group we do not have $k(a,b)=(ka,b)$, correct? I think I got used to that fact without carefully studying free group.

Comment: @GReyes I actually also really love talking about this discussion that sometimes I look at such topics in math educators SE. :D I agree about over-formalization, and certainly even more after this question. Also, I thought introducing $a * b:=ab$ in abstract algebra intro was not a problem, but now, just now, I start to feel like less "stuff like this" actually can help a lot in understanding math hehe

Comment: @Popyaitte I meant in this specific free group.

Comment: @21understanding Yep thats it ! And again about over-formalisation, I think it is very hard at the beginning, but once you got it, formal arguments become a very powerful tool (but not pedagogic ones ;)).

Answer (score 1):

It is better to start with the goal: you are looking for an $R$-module $V\otimes W$ and a bilinear map $f: V\times W \to V\otimes W$ that has the property that for any bilinear map $g$ out of $V\times W$ into an $R$-module $X$, there is a unique $\textit{linear}$ map $u:V\otimes W\to X$ such that the following diagram commutes. That is, $g$ factors through $f$ uniquely:

[image]

Of course, for this to make sense, you actually have to prove that there $\textit{is}$ such an object and an associated map that has the above property.

The construction itself is done by starting with the free group and the word "free" tells the story: the free group consists formal sums; there are no relations. By taking the quotient, you are identifying elements within the free group, so the object you get is not "free" any more. But the quotient and the associated map it induces prove the existence of an object that satisfies the universal property above. I imagine the next thing Hungerford does give is the map $f$ and prove that the quotient satisfies the UMP. After you do this, the quotient itself is never really used again.